# Object not recognized as JSON object

Tags: json, reactjs, leaflet

Short story: I am making my own GIS (geographic information system) and want to be able to upload JSON files with geographical data. I do not however want to save files in a database, just in a list. Furthermore I'm using Context to parse data to the `<MAP/>` (leaflet) component.

My problem is that when pushing the JSON to the list it is not recogniezed as a JSON but as string. How can I solve this problem.

I am quite new to react so I am open for suggestions to solve it differently.

Here is my code

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import "../../App.css";
import data from '../../Layers/layer1.json'
import data1 from '../../Layers/layer2.json'


export const FileContext = createContext()

const layerList = []

function updateList(layer){
    layerList.push(layer)
}


export const FileProvider = (props) => {
    
    const [layer, setLayer] = useState(
        layerList
    )

    return(
        <FileContext.Provider value = {[layer, setLayer]}>
            {props.children}
        </FileContext.Provider>
    );
}

    // Create an object of formData 
const onFileChange = e => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = e => {
        console.log(e.target.result);
        updateList(e.target.result);
        console.log(layerList)
    };
    //console.log(layerList)
    }


function FileUpload() {

  return (
    <div>
        <div id='fileupload'>
            <input type="file" onChange={onFileChange} />
        </div>
    </div>


  );
}

export default FileUpload;
```

And this is the Map component

```
import { Map, TileLayer, GeoJSON} from 'react-leaflet'
import "../App.css";
import data from '../Layers/layer1.json'
import { FileContext } from '../LandingPage/ToolbarComponents/FileUpload';



function MapOslo() {

  const [layer, setLayer] = useContext(FileContext)

  return (
      <Map center={[59.93, 10.75]} zoom={4}>
          <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          <GeoJSON data={layer} style={['color','#006400']} />
      </Map>
  );
}

export default MapOslo;
```

Comment: I assume that you use webpack, and if thats right you need to use plugin for import json as object https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/

Answer (score 0):

To convert a String to JSON you can use `JSON.parse(str)`

```
var jsonStr = "{test: 'hi'}";
var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

So I think you have to implement `parse` here: `updateList(JSON.parse(e.target.result));`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It is now regocnized as an object but it does not work now either, might be a problem with the map not rendering a second time